# NativeScript-Vue with Typescript in VSCode with Vetur: Alert with then giving Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nativescript, nativescript-vue, vetur

I'm using VSCode with Vetur. This is my code:

```
alert({
  title: 'Success!',
  message: 'Account created successfully',
  okButtonText: 'Okay'
  }).then(() => {
  console.log('Alert dialog closed!');
})
```

I get the error `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' Vetur(2339)`

I just follow the instructions in the docs here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/dialogs/alert/

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or have setup any linter?

Comment: Yes, I'm using TypeScript with ESLint and Vetur extensions in VSCode

Comment: Then I think it must be your tsconfig or Vetur extensions, I'm not exactly sure. But I can say for sure that alert supports promise in {N}. You can simply bypass the compiler error by casting alert to any.

Comment: Okay, let me try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT for Nativescript 7:

```
import {Dialogs} from "@nativescript/core";
```

then use

```
Dialogs.alert({
  foo
});
```

or whatever you need from the Dialogs module.

Original answer:

Make sure to either

```
import { alert } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs'
```

edit:
or (thanks ayudh)

```
import { alert } from '@nativescript/core/ui/dialogs'
```